# Php execute function on form submit not working

Tags: php

I've got the code below and I'm trying to have it so I can have an input box which I submit, and then it uses the input box as the text in the image generated.

```
<form id="MyForm" method="post" action="process()">
<input>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
function process()
{
/* Create some objects */
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'gray' );

/* New image */
$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);

/* Black text */
$draw->setFillColor('black');

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

/* Create text */
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, 
    'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
}
?>
```

When I try this code it says file www.site.com/process() not found. I followed a tutorial to get this so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: php is server side so of course the above will not work.

Comment: `process()` what it gives ?

Comment: calling a function in form's action attribute? you are doing it wrong.

Comment: you will have to set a `name` attribute for one of your controls and then do something like this `if (isset($_POST['<name_of_input>'])) { process(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `action` attribute needs to be a URL.

That URL can one handled by a PHP script. That PHP script can run a function.

You could run the function for any request to that URL, or use an `if` statement to examine the data submitted by the form (at the moment, there is no data, so you would have to put some in the form first) and call the function conditionally.

---

**NB** Your PHP script can't simultaneously output `text/html` and `image/png` data. You have to pick *one* file to send to the browser.

---

If you want to run a function *directly* from a form submission, then you need to run the code in the browser instead of the server, write the code in JavaScript, and bind the function as an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the form's `submit` event.

Comment: Hi. So you recommend I call out to a PHP file from my HTML form, like this: ```<form id="MyForm" method="post" action="myfile.php">```

Comment: @Jimmy — It isn't so much a recommendation as it is the only way the approach you are taking can work. (The only alternative would be to make the HTTP request with JavaScript instead of submitting a form)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by adding a name to one of your form controls and then check so this value is set on form submission:

```
<!-- submit the form to the same page -->
<form id="MyForm" method="post" action="/">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

// check if the form is set in the $_POST array
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  process();
}
```

Comment: That won't work. The `process` function tries to output an image. You can't do that after you've already output some HTML.

Comment: @Quentin - of course I know that but the above example is only to show how to call execute php code on a form submission. I'm not going to write the code for him =)

Comment: Hi@Cyclonecode thank you for the information. So should I have an HTML file with the form, which has the post action going out to say myfile.php ```<form id="MyForm" method="post" action="myfile.php">```